# Cannot adjust inset to show at the top of the base graph

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to put an inset on top of a graph, the inset is also a graph.
I'm using `Inset` within `Epilog` and the following command line:

```
Epilog -> {Inset[coherenceLengthGraph, {12, 0.35}, {Automatic, Top}, 11]}
```

I've tried many things yet I cannot put the inset above the base graph.

---

I'm using Show to render two lists of different data on the same graph, after that -and within Show- I use Epilog. I looked at GraphicsColumn but I couldn't see how it allows things that one can do using Inset.

Here's my code

```
 pwaveGraph = Show[graphlistofKPPhaseBoundaries, graphKPBands,
   Frame -> {True},
   FrameLabel -> {"2μm/\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[HBar]\), \
\(2\)]\)", "" }, PlotRange -> {{-2, 18.05}, {-1.05, 1.05}},
   FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {-1, 0, 1}}, 
   Epilog -> {Inset[
      coherenceLengthGraph, {12, 0.35}, {Automatic, Top}, 11]}];
```

Comment: If you want it to be strictly above the base graph, and not overlapping with it, why don't you use `Column` instead of `Inset`?  Also, please provide some more information about what you are doing.  `Epilog` is not an option for `Graph` (it works in `Show` and `Graphcis` though)

Comment: I realise you were talking about graphics, not graphs (as in networks).  Column/GraphicsColumn should still be useful.  Can you please try it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Please consider registering your account so that any upvotes you get on this question are added to those you might get on future questions and answers. That way, over time [you will be able to do more on the site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/privileges) (post graphics, edit things, etc).

Comment: @AykutTeker Please add your code into your question as an edit rather than squeezing it into a comment, where it is all but unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that stays with the approach you started:

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Background -> Lighter[Orange]];

With[{insetWidth = Pi, insetHeight = 1.6, extraPixels = 120},
 Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
  Epilog -> Inset[p,
    {Pi, insetHeight},
    {Automatic, Automatic},
    insetWidth
    ],
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, extraPixels}}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False]
 ]
```

[image: pic inset]

I added `ImagePadding` and suppressed `PlotRangeClipping`.

Answer (score 0):

Exact `Inset` positioning sometimes requires a bit of trial and error. Here is a variation of @Jens approach using `Locator`

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Background -> Lighter[Orange]];
extraPixels = 120;
pt = ImageScaled[{0.5, 0.8}];

plot = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Epilog -> Dynamic@Locator[Dynamic@pt, p, LocatorRegion -> Full],
  ImageSize -> {400, 300 + extraPixels}, AspectRatio -> 3/4, 
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, extraPixels}}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, Frame -> True]
```

For repeat plots you can now get the locator coordinates and use them from now on in an inset

```
coords = First@
   Cases[plot /. Dynamic -> Identity, x_ImageScaled, \[Infinity]];

Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Epilog -> Inset[inset, coords],
 ImageSize -> {400, 300 + extraPixels}, AspectRatio -> 3/4, 
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, extraPixels}}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, Frame -> True]
```