# Positioning a subplot using Inset in the main plot with image or scaled coordinates

Tags: plotting

I have generated a plot and subplot fine, and I would like to position it in the top right corner of the main plot. Ordinarily I would use the position options. However, my notebook is used for processing multiple data sets and the axes change, so I can't position the subplot using coordinates of the main plot.

Could I use pixels or the size of the main plot or get the maximum values on the x- and y-axis for the positioning?

Comment: This may help http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15578/cannot-adjust-inset-to-show-at-the-top-of-the-base-graph

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example with `Scaled` coordinates:

```
SetOptions[Plot, Frame -> True, Axes -> False];

mainplot = Plot[Exp[x], {x, -3, 3}]

subplot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}]

Show[mainplot, 
 Epilog -> Inset[subplot, Scaled[{1, 1}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]]
```

Returns

[image]

Check the documentation of [Inset](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) for details

Comment: Perfect! Different approach to what I was using!

Comment: Glad to help. The next step (in my example) would be to fiddle around with `PlotRange` and/or `Background` to prevent the unsightly overlap of `Exp[x]` over the inset, but that's moving beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Yeah that's fine, I altered the FrameTicks to compensate. It's a good solution you have posted. Before I was just using a listlineplot with epilog and a second listlineplot positioned based on the coordiantes of the main plot which is a hopeless way of doing things!